# Correctly differentiate wrt product of variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, rule

I have a function f(x) for which I would need to differentiate and then evaluate it to some product x = y*z. Naively, Mathematica does not accept:

```
D[f[y*z], y*z]
```

Now, I can somewhat force it by using a rule like so:

```
D[f[x], x] /. x -> y*z
```

Now, the problem is that the substitution, for example

```
rule = f[y*z] -> y*z
D[f[x], x] /. x -> y*z /. rule
```

is not performed at all. Here, I would of course expect the answer to be 1.
How can I make this work as intended?

Comment: Your rule is that f[y, z] should be replaced with y z but f[y, z] never shows up in the expression you show, only f[x] does.

Comment: Sorry, the notation is maybe not very clear. The space between "y" and "z" is understood as multiplication. I amended this in the question for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put spaces only but the commas snuck in. `D[f[x], x] /. x -> y*z` yields `f'[y z]`. There is nothing for your rule to replace because your rule only acts on plain `f[y z]` and not `f'`. Does something more like `f = y z; D[f, y z]/.y z-> x` work for you? This yields 1 (along with a warning, but that can be suppressed with `Quiet` or through some clever application of `Hold` perhaps).

Comment: How is `f` defined? Can you just use `f'[y z]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using [`Derivative`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html).

```
Derivative[1][f][y*z]
```

A shorter way to write the very same is

```
f'[y*z]
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacement rules act on the internal structure of the expression. You can use [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) to see the structure.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

D[f[x], x] /. x -> y*z//FullForm

(* Derivative[1][f][Times[y, z]] *)

(rule = f[y*z] -> y*z)//FullForm

(* Rule[f[Times[y, z]], Times[y, z]] *)
```

The LHS of the rule does not appear in the expression, so no replacement is made.

```
D[f[x], x] /. x -> y*z /. rule

(* f'[y z] *)
```

If you use a pure function in the rule, you will get what you expect

```
(rule = f -> (#1 & ))//FullForm

(* Rule[f, Function[Slot[1]]] *)
```

The LHS of the rule (i.e., `f`) appears in the expression, so

```
D[f[x], x] /. x -> y*z /. rule

(* 1 *)
```